# Azure Batch AI recipes: Saving results to storage

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning

I'm using Batch Ai to run keras models on azure. Unfortunately
I do not know how to save my result. I checked the VMs and 
there is definitely something there in /mnt/batch/tasks...
I think.

```
"outputDirectories": [
      {
        "createNew": true,
        "id": "MODEL",
        "pathPrefix": "$AZ_BATCHAI_MOUNT_ROOT/external",
        "pathSuffix": "Models",
        "type": "custom"
      }
],
```

Std out works just fine and the job.json from the examples defines an output directory for results as well, but they never get copied into
the storage. What am I missing?

Should I define the save path in my python script and copy them by hand to
*$AZ_BATCHAI_MOUNT_ROOT*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is interested in the solution. I posted my question to [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/BatchAI/issues/24#issuecomment-361182316) as well.

A contributor was kind enough to answer my question.